# How do I modify this Formula?

Tags: formula

Currently I have the following:

```
AND(

   ISPICKVAL(Origin,'Email - Support')
   ISBLANK(First_Manual_Email_Response__c),
   CreatedBy.UserRoleId = '00E60000000mH2JEAU' 
)
```

I've realized I need to adjust the formula so that it reads if the origin = email support OR if it's created by the UserRole AND the first Manual Email Response is blank. How do I incorporate the OR into the formula instead of the AND?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be

```
OR(

   ISPICKVAL(Origin,'Email - Support'),
   AND (
         ISBLANK(First_Manual_Email_Response__c),
         CreatedBy.UserRoleId = '00E60000000mH2JEAU'
   ) 
)
```